# Here SDK Flutter 3.0

Tags: android, flutter, here-api, heremaps

Im Using Here SDK for Flutter. Now with the Flutter 3.0 update it broke.

I tried to change the null aware operators inside that package and the

> plugins/here_sdk/lib/src/sdk/mapview/here_map.dart

---> No more errors.

inside

> plugins/here_sdk/android/src/main/kotlin/com/here/mapview/MapController.kt

line 52

```
      plugin.registrar!!.activity().application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
```

changed to:

```
      plugin.registrar!!.activity()!.application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
```

line 114:

```
  plugin.registrar!!.activity().application.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
```

changed to :

```
  plugin.registrar!!.activity()!.application.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
```

Now the maps Builds but is in some kind of between state. There is no error and the map is not controllable.

---> Rest of my UI doesn't build.

Should i wait for the Offical update or stay with Flutter 2.10.5 ?

Comment: stay with Flutter 2.10.5 for now when library updates you can update to 3.0

Comment: As of now, the latest supported Flutter version is 4.10.2:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.11.3.0/dev_guide/topics/about.html#minimum-requirements

Please wait until Flutter 3 support is officially announced in the HERE SDK release notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since 4.12.7 you actually do. Forgot to answer.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.12.7.0/dev_guide/topics/about.html

Answer (score 0):

As told in comment the we are not supporting the Flutter 3.

Please check the [minimum-requirements](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.11.3.0/dev_guide/topics/about.html#minimum-requirements) for the HERE SDK flutter.